# In intents why Uri is uses to transferring the data .

Tags: android, android-intent

Because we can use , File and for small things we can also use Strings &

please Explain Intent with some real world example .

in "`ACTION_DELETE`" we are not dealing with Any Activity & what is the the use of intent with "`ACTION_DELETE`" Action , and in "`ACTION_DIAL`" we are dealing with Activity ..... this is confusing , i am getting the proper meaning of intent .

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html carefully.

Comment: refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html